# Delete old "Faces" and other data and thumbnails in iPhoto 9.5.1

Tags: photos.app, photos, macos, data

I split my iPhoto Library into two by:

1. Duplicating it
2. Deleting most old photos from the **new** one I will continue to use (and emptying the iPhoto trash)
3. Deleting the photos from the **archived** one that will stay in the new library

The issue is that currently, the **new** library still contains "Faces" and other thumbnail data from photos that have already been deleted (but preserved in the separate **archived** one).

These are contained in the `Data`, `Data.noindex`, `Originals`, `Thubmnails`, `Masters`, `Modified`, and other directories.

I rebuilt the library with all four methods in iPhoto 9.5.1 following [Apple's instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2638), but to no avail.

How can I free this new library of legacy files?

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems tedious, it may be better to export all your photos out of a library and then create a new iPhoto Library and then import them to the new one. I'm also yet to discover a way to 'purge' data that is no longer relevant/needed.

Comment: The issue with this is that edits, events, albums, etc. are not preserved.